# Multithreaded matrix multiplication in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a Java program that uses threads to multiply two matrices. I have the following code:

```
public class MatrixMultiplication {
    //Declare matrices
    public static int[][] matrix1 = new int[][]{
            {1,2,3,4},{3,2,1,4}
    };
    public static int[][] matrix2 = new int[][]{
            {2,1,3,4},{4,2,5,3}
    };
    public static int[][] result = new int[4][4];
    //Threads
    public static Thread[][] threads = new Thread[4][4];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //create worker threads with M and N hard-coded
        for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < threads[i].length; l++) {
                threads[i][l] = new Thread(new Worker(matrix1, matrix2, result, i, l));
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
            for(int l = 0; l < threads[i].length; i++){
                try {
                    threads[i][l].start();
                    threads[i][l].join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Contents of result matrix");
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for(int l = 0; l < 4; l++){
                System.out.println("["+i+","+l+"] = "+result[i][l]);
            }
    }


}

class Worker implements Runnable{
    int[][] m1;
    int[][] m2;
    int[][] result;
    int row;
    int col;

    public Worker(int[][]m1, int[][] m2, int[][] result, int row, int col){
        this.m1 = m1;
        this.m2 = m2;
        this.result = result;
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }


    public void run(){result[row][col] = (m1[row][col] * m2[col][col]) + (m1[row][col+1] * m2[col+1][col]);}
}
```

The programming is throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on multiple lines, notable lines 21 and in the run method of the Worker thread class. I have tried several variations to no avail and am looking for guidance on this. Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the point of multi-threading this if you block every thread's execution until it terminates?

Comment: You tried several variations, but you obviously did not step it through. You use col+1 as index into the matrix. Look at what values col will take.

Answer (score 0):

There is several points of problem.  On line 21 you use `I+1` instead of `L+1`.  Also, matrix are two-dimensional arrays with only two lines, not four.